# Can Chronicle Queue method writer be shared between threads?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

And a second question that follows if method writer (MW) can be shared:

> Is it advised from performance reasons ? (or it is better to have a single MW per thread ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is advised to avoid sharing the method writer between threads as this is not well tested. It should work, but might not. You should have one per thread ideally as this is how it is generally used.